# Downloading a LOT of files using python

Tags: python, download, urllib2

Is there a good way to download a lot of files en masse using python? This code is speedy enough for downloading about 100 or so files. But I need to download 300,000 files. Obviously they are all very small files (or I wouldn't be downloading 300,000 of them :) ) so the real bottleneck seems to be this loop. Does anyone have any thoughts? Maybe using MPI or threading?

Do I just have to live with the bottle neck? Or is there a faster way, maybe not even using python?

(I included the full beginning of the code just for completeness sake)

```
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import urllib2
import os
import linecache 

#we start with a huge file of urls

data= pd.read_csv("edgar.csv")
datatemp2=data[data['form'].str.contains("14A")]
datatemp3=data[data['form'].str.contains("14C")]

#data2 is the cut-down file

data2=datatemp2.append(datatemp3)
flist=np.array(data2['filename'])
print len(flist)
print flist

###below we have a script to download all of the files in the data2 database
###here you will need to create a new directory named edgar14A14C in your CWD

original=os.getcwd().copy()
os.chdir(str(os.getcwd())+str('/edgar14A14C'))


for i in xrange(len(flist)):
    url = "ftp://ftp.sec.gov/"+str(flist[i])
    file_name = str(url.split('/')[-1])
    u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    f = open(file_name, 'wb')
    f.write(u.read())
    f.close()
    print i
```

Comment: `multiprocessing` will allow you to get some speedups from your other cores (you will need to split your bigger list into X smaller lists and job one list out to each core)

Comment: Do you have any control of the server? Could you cause the server to zip and send the files in question when needed?

Comment: @dawg: I do not, otherwise grabbing them on the fly would probably be the best solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The usual pattern with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) is to create a `job()` function that takes arguments and performs some potentially CPU bound work.

**Example:** (*based on your code*)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def job(url):
    file_name = str(url.split('/')[-1])
    u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    f = open(file_name, 'wb')
    f.write(u.read())
    f.close()

pool = Pool()
urls = ["ftp://ftp.sec.gov/{0:s}".format(f) for f in flist]
pool.map(job, urls)
```

This will do a number of things:

- Create a multiprocessing pool and set of workers as you have CPU(s) or CPU Core(s)
- Create a list of inputs to the `job()` function.
- Map the list of inputs `urls` to `job()` and wait for all jobs to complete.

Python's `multiprocessing.Pool.map` will take care of splitting up your input across the no. of workers in the pool.

Another useful neat little thing I've done for this kind of work is to use [progress](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progress) like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


from progress.bar import Bar


def job(input):
    # do some work


pool = Pool()
inputs = range(100)
bar = Bar('Processing', max=len(inputs))
for i in pool.imap(job, inputs):
    bar.next()
bar.finish()
```

This gives you a nice progress bar on your console as your jobs are progressing so you have some idea of progress and eta, etc.

I also find the [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) library very useful here and a much nicer set of API(s) for dealing with web resources and downloading of content.

Comment: Yes this looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I will give this a run and return and report. 

By the way, is there a way to specify how many cores I want to designate to the pool? I am running this on a sort-of-supercomputer and I don't know if it would be good form to take up ALL of the cores :)

Comment: I tried running the code above just without the bar and it throws an error. :   

     urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error ftp error: >

Any ideas? It seems that urllib2 cant open the file.

Comment: Answering my own question above for posterity, I changed 
pool = Pool() to 
pool = Pool(processes=4) as a test and now I do not get the URL error but I am now getting a pickling error. PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed

Comment: So I figured out that it is working but not completely. The error messages were each getting thrown for a specific process only. So if I was wanting to download 100 files 98 would download but 2 would not because of the errors. I think that warrants a further investigation but is beyond the scope of my original question so I will accept this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those that want to use `requests`, `tqdm` and `concurrent.futures`:

(Note that `ThreadPoolExecutor` can be replaced by `ProcessPoolExecutor` if needed.)

```py
import os
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import tqdm

urls = []  # LIST OF URLS
LOCAL_DIR = "my/dir"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(LOCAL_DIR), exist_ok=True)

def download_image(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        file_name = str(url.split('/')[-1])
        file_path = os.path.join(LOCAL_DIR, file_name)
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)
        print(f"Image downloaded successfully from {url} and saved to {file_path}")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error downloading the image from {url}: {e}")

def download_images_in_parallel(urls):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        list(tqdm.tqdm(executor.map(download_image, urls), total=len(urls)))

download_images_in_parallel(urls)
```