# How to use multithreading in python to download multiple files simultaneously

Tags: python, download, multiprocessing, urllib, python-multithreading

I have a link to a folder which has enormous number of files that I want to download. I started downloading it single file at a time, however it's taking a very long time. Is there a way to spawn some multi-threaded processes to download maybe a batch of files simultaneously. Probably like process1 downloads the first 20 files in the folder, process2 downloads the next 20 simultaneously and so on.

Right now, I'm doing as follows:

```
import urllib, os
os.chdir('/directory/to/save/the/file/to')
url = 'http://urltosite/folderthathasfiles
urllib.urlretrieve(url)
```

Comment: how about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398044/downloading-a-lot-of-files-using-python

Answer (score 4):

You can define a `function` that takes the `link` and a `list` of `filenames` then it will loop through the `list` and download `files`, then create a `thread` for each `list` and have it target the `function`. For example:

```
def download_files(url, filenames):
    for filename in filenames:
        urllib.urlretrieve(os.path.join(url,filename))

# then create the lists and threads
url = 'test.url'
files = [[file1, file2, file3....], [file21, file22, file23...]...]
for lst in files:
    threading.Thread(target=download_files, args=(url, lst)).start()
```

Comment: Great, but is there a way to read all files from that folder into multiple lists? Like first 20 in one list, next 20 in the next and so on. Because otherwise, due to the enormous number of files in the folder it will not be possible to write all the files in multiple lists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589241/downloading-files-from-an-http-server-in-python%3E and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023530/python-to-list-http-files-and-directories should be helpful for that